# Custom middleware doesn't redirect

Tags: django

I'm writing a simple custom middleware that is supposed to redirect all users to a specific page if a settings constante is set to True:

from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.conf import settings

```
class DisableSiteMiddleware( object ):
    """If site is disabled, user is redirected to a simple page"""
    print( "Class" )

    def process_request( self, request ):
        print( "func" )
        if settings.SITE_DISABLED == True:
            return redirect( "/site-disabled" )
```

In urls.py, but does it with any url

```
url( r'^site-disabled/', site_disabled )
```

What happens is curious: on browser side it won't load anything and display a browser failure page. On the console I can see it prints repeatedly "func" which means that process_request is called several times. I suspect a loop being killed by the browser.

What could be the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No magics here.

It is redirecting to `/site-disabled` every time. Put conditions on top of it.

Comment: What kind of condition ?

Comment: current is `settings.SITE_DISABLED == True` . In every request it is same. So do whatever conditions you want.

Comment: I added a simple boolean has_redirected = False which is check and changed accordingly.